# wrap html tags to make all clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-widget

I'm looking to turn an entire row clickable. Right now the rows look like

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>      
<tr>
            <label for="object_303">
                <td><input checked="checked" id="object_303" name="objects" type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Group</td>
                <td>Obj name</td>
            </label>
        </tr>
</table>
```

This seems to correctly match http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_label_default_css which shows how wrapping in a label makes it all clickable.

How can I wrap this entire row to be clickable? Salamat

Comment: Wrapping the contents of a table row doesn't make sense; the direct children of a `<tr>` must be either `<td>` or `<th>` elements.

Comment: Just put a "click" handler on the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some jQuery up top.  Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#row1").click(function() {
        ($(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked")));
    });
});
</script>
<table>      
<tr id="row1">
                <td><input checked="checked" id="object_303" name="objects" type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td>Group</td>
                <td>Obj name</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

You can also generalize this by changing the jquery selector.  If you want all `<tr>`s to behave this way, just change the `"#row1"` selector to `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is broken... Only thead, tbody or tr should be inside the table.  Inside tr should be td.  As @Pointy suggested, placing a class in tr tag references the entire row. I amended your code, see below, and notice where the `<label>` tags are.

```
<table>      
<tr class="myclass">
<td>
  <label for="object_303">
    <input checked="checked" id="object_303" name="objects" type="checkbox"/>
  </label>
</td>
<td>Group</td>
<td>Obj name</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And jquery:

```
$(".myclass").click( myFunction );
```

Comment: in the w3 example, you can wrap other child tags like `p` in label and it works. I'm trying to make the `td` tags clickable, in other words the row itself

Comment: Okay - I beg to differ about placing the label tag where you placed it - However, if your goal is to make the entire row clickable, then my code does exactly that.  The tr tag has class myclass, the tr tag refers to the entire row, and an event has been applied to that class (and thus, the entire row).

Comment: I don't know what w3 example you are referring to. The only w3 site I know is http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp and it fails to mention label tag inside table, outside tr tag.

Comment: it seems the only one you can wrap is `radio` buttons, not checkboxes. which leaves me absolutely flabbergasted. they seem pretty similar

Comment: You are either mis-reading a document, or reading a bad document. I suggest you find alternative source of help text or book.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully one more time. Your code doesn't match with w3c, you don't need to wrap element with label tag. 
Label's `for` attribute and input's `id` should match.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>      
  <tr>
    <td><input checked="checked" id="object_303" name="objects" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td><label for="object_303"> Group obj name</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `for` and `id` do match. I'm trying to make the 2 `td` tags clickable

Comment: By not matching i meant wrapping element with label tag. You can make as many clickable element as you want just put another label with `for` attribute. `<td><label for="object_303"> 1</label></td><td><label for="object_303"> 2</label></td>` Will work.

Comment: while that might be true, wrapping several `td` elements with label did work in the w3 code emulator

Comment: @codyc4321yes, but for purpose making label clickable, you don't need to wrap it. Click action is provided with `for` attribute. More of that in many cases it is semantic incorrect (for example wrapping p or h3 with label tag will cause an error) .